# How to enforce Lua scripts runtime limit?

Tags: lua, timeout, sandbox

Running an almost trivial script in lua with dofile, 10000 times, takes about 52 seconds in this machine, but if i run 10000 times "lua52 script.lua", it takes 3 or 4 times more. I'm aware that there's more system calls involved and other overhead, but what i try to achieve is running scripts with a timeout of let's say 3 seconds, and print out the output.
My problem is scripts with infinite loops, intentional or not, for example:

```
while(true) do
end
```

Can i make a timeout for a dofile from within Lua?
Is my only option to call the interpreter each time with timeout(3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It feels a bit wrong for a novice like me to be correcting lhf on Lua matters, but here goes; passing "count" to debug.sethook is the same as passing "c" or "call", the correct mask to pass to fire the associated function after *n* VM instructions is "".

As such, to restrict the runtime of code loaded from dofile(), use something like the following:

```
local f = function() error("timeout") end
local x,y = xpcall(function()
  debug.sethook(f, "", 1e8)
  local ret = dofile("script.lua")
  debug.sethook()
  return ret
end, debug.traceback)
```

Comment: `count` works fine for me. The code I gave aborts with `stdin:1: timeout!`.

Comment: That's odd; passing `"count"` works as expected in the code you posted, but it aborts instantly in the code I posted (script.lua just contains `while true do end`).  Passing `""` works as expected in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't call out to C functions in your scripts you can use the *count* hook with a large count value and raise an error inside the hook:

```
local function f() error"timeout!" end
debug.sethook(f,"count",1e6)
while true do end
```

In your application, set the *count* hook  before calling *dofile*.

The *count* hook is called every *n* Lua VM instructions. However, there is not way to account for the time taken in C functions, hence my caveat above.

Comment: can you explain a little more about this? i'll appreciate it.

Comment: I've tried your code and it doesn't even enter the while loop, what i'm missing?

Comment: @alfa64, If you tried it in the interactive interpreter, remove `local`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in facilities, try using [lalarm](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lalarm) library.